# Converting a Ruby hash string to a Python dictionary

Tags: python, ruby, parsing, dictionary, hashmap

I'm working with some command output that's returned as the string of a Ruby hash. (From something called mcollective).

Here is an example string I'm receiving:

```
{:changes=>{"total"=>0},     :events=>{"failure"=>0, "success"=>0, "total"=>0},     :version=>      {"puppet"=>"2.7.21 (Puppet Enterprise 2.8.1)", "config"=>1381497648},     :time=>      {"filebucket"=>0.000287,       "cron"=>0.00212,       "package"=>0.398982,       "exec"=>0.001314,       "config_retrieval"=>5.60761618614197,       "anchor"=>0.001157,       "service"=>0.774906,       "total"=>9.85111718614197,       "host"=>0.002662,       "user"=>0.063606,       "file"=>2.998467,       "last_run"=>1381497660},     :resources=>      {"skipped"=>6,       "failed_to_restart"=>0,       "out_of_sync"=>0,       "failed"=>0,       "total"=>112,       "restarted"=>0,       "scheduled"=>0,       "changed"=>0}}
```

I'm capable of writing a mini parser for this, but it would be a fiddly task. Does anyone know of a library or code snippet that could convert this for me into a Python dictionary?

If you think I should just parse it, any tips are welcome.

Comment: A quick hack would be to just replace => with : and :[a-z]+ with "\1" and then call ast.literal_eval or json.loads. That wouldn't be correct since it ignores string literals, but it might be good enough for now.

Comment: According to their docs http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/reference/basic/basic_cli_usage.html they also can export JSON: `-j` flag.

Comment: Not in the version im running unfortunately. But yeah that would be best

Comment: It's really weird that something would send a string representation of a Ruby hash. A Ruby developer should know better than to do that and would use JSON or YAML. Can you show us sample code describing how you make the call and receive the resulting data string, and how you're looking at it? Can you use cURL to retrieve the data and look at it completely outside of Ruby or Python?

Comment: It's from the output of mcollective, so you have seen the string called from outside of ruby or python. The string you see is the output from this program which runs outside of ruby or python. You can find out more about this from http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it wasn't too bad to write something good enough for my needs. Not the prettiest thing, but it will do for me.

```
# Sometimes MCO gives us a ruby hash as a string, We can coerce this into json then into dictionary
def convert_hash_to_dict(self,ruby_hash):
    dict_str = ruby_hash.replace(":",'"')    # Remove the ruby object key prefix
    dict_str = dict_str.replace("=>",'" : ') # swap the k => v notation, and close any unshut quotes 
    dict_str = dict_str.replace('""','"')    # strip back any double quotes we created to sinlges
    return json.loads(dict_str)
```

Comment: For posterity, that last replace call will replace any empty fields like `key: ""` with `key: "`

Answer (score 7):

You can easily convert it to JSON using the following command:

```
ruby -e 'require "json"; puts JSON.generate({:ruby_hash => "whatever etc..."})'
```

Then use Python's JSON library to parse it.

Comment: This is a possibility, - it does require me to ensure there a ruby interpreter on the system tho, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using Ruby to serialize this to JSON? That way you can de-serialize it with Python's JSON library.

If that's not an option, you can define a custom structured language parser with relative ease using this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Parsley