# JSON format issue in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to executing rest api get using python script.Below the code I am using.But api response doesn't have proper Json format I am getting error.

```
import requests 
  
# api-endpoint 
URL = "end point url"
  
 # sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = URL)
  
# extracting data in json format 
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

My api response below

```
[{:mac_address=>"10:55", :Parameter=>"Device.Info", :status=>"Success", :response_code=>"200", :value=>"2.4Ghz"}]
```

I need to change response as below

```
[{"mac_address":"10:55","Parameter":"Device.Info","status":"Success","response_code":"200","value":"2.4Ghz"}]
```

How to achieve this in python? I am new to  python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Ruby hash string to a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319436/converting-a-ruby-hash-string-to-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
test = '[{:mac_address=>"10:55", :Parameter=>"Device.Info", :status=>"Success", :response_code=>"200", :value=>"2.4Ghz"}]'

def to_json(val: str):
    val = val.replace("{:", '{"').replace(" :", '"').replace("=>", '":')
    return val


res = to_json(test)
print(res)
```

result:

> [{"mac_address":"10:55","Parameter":"Device.Info","status":"Success","response_code":"200","value":"2.4Ghz"}]

in your case:

```py
import requests 
import json

def to_json(val: str):
    val = val.replace("{:", '{"').replace(" :", '"').replace("=>", '":')
    return val
  
# api-endpoint 
URL = "end point url"
  
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = URL)
  
# extracting data in string format 
data = r.text

# converting string to json object
res = json.loads(to_json(data))

print(res)
```

Comment: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: def to_json(val: str):
    val = val.replace("{:", '{"').replace(" :", '"').replace("=>", '":')
    return val
data = r.json()


res = to_json(data)
print(res)

Comment: you should call this method on r.text `to_json(r.text)`

Comment: Then you should cast the result to json by using json.loads(res). (don't forget to `import json`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get a plain text response, you can  manually re-format the response using `String.replace()`:

```py
response = '[{:mac_address=>"10:55", :Parameter=>"Device.Info", :status=>"Success", :response_code=>"200", :value=>"2.4Ghz"}]'

desired = {}

response = response[2:-3].replace('"', '').split(', ')
for r in response:
  key, value = r.split('=>')
  key = key.replace(':','')
  desired[key] = value
```